# Is there any way to hide banners in article but keep them in category list?

Tags: joomla-3.x, com-banners

I have a website running under Joomla 3.10.11, which displays various banner modules on all post category pages.

The goal is to NOT show any banner when the user enters the article page. Is it possible without changing any layouts?

Answer (score 2):

**Easy ways css ways**

Put banner class like .showbanner-oncat
Then in menu category add css

```
.showbanner-oncat{display:block}
```

in menu default handle article add css

```
.showbanner-oncat{display:none}
```

**custom ways**

Override the mod banner view
Then do

```
    if ($context === 'com_content.article'}{

       $wa->addCssDeclaration('.showbanner-oncat{display:none}');
    }
    else{
       $wa->addCssDeclaration('.showbanner-oncat{display:block}');
    }
```

But these are still impact the peformance, maybe a little ms and the banner js still load if display none set up.

**joomla ways**

You can make config association menu to display the module only on some menu

**You are full control**

You need do custom model to cut the peformance loss

```
if ($context === 'com.content.category`){
 do dbo and pass the view.
}
else {return}
```

Comment: As you said, css way have performance impact so I need to explore Joomla ways preferably. Thanks for your suggestions